# Data did not display in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new here, please correct me if I ask wrongly.

I did this stored procedure, however, when I execute it, only `ErrorNumber`, `SPName` and `ErrorMessage` came out.

Can someone please explain to me what I did wrong? Thanks.

This is what I executed:

```
exec dbo.spPartMasterExtension @DomainSite = 'BRIS0011', @ItemNo='1002424251911',
                               @ItemDescription = 'New Item', @ItemValue = '1',
                               @ItemUM = '1', @EmployeeNo = 'nn031097'
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPartMasterExtension]
   @DomainSite nvarchar(8),
   @ItemNo nvarchar(18),
   @ItemDescription nvarchar(50),
   @ItemValue nvarchar(50),
   @ItemUM nvarchar(50),
   @EmployeeNo nvarchar(18)
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @ErrorNo integer = '',
           @SPName nvarchar(max) = '',
           @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max) = ''
  Declare @ItemUMOriginal nvarchar(50)

  IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PartMasterExtension 
             WHERE ItemNo = @ItemNo and ItemDescription = @ItemDescription and DomainSite =@DomainSite)
  BEGIN
      UPDATE PartMasterExtension 
      SET ItemValue = @ItemValue, 
          ItemUM = @ItemUM,
          DateTimeStamp = GETDATE(),
          EmployeeNo = @EmployeeNo 
      WHERE 
          ItemNo = @ItemNo AND ItemDescription = @ItemDescription AND DomainSite = @DomainSite 
  END
  ELSE 
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO PartMasterExtension
           SELECT 
               @DomainSite, @ItemNo, @ItemDescription,
               @ItemValue, @ItemUM, getdate(), @EmployeeNo
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         SELECT 
            @ErrorNo = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @SPName = ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
  END

  SELECT 
    @ErrorNo as ErrorNumber,
    @SPName as SPName, 
    @ErrorMessage AS ErrorMessage;
END
GO
```

Comment: Looks like you're only going to return a result in the case of an error.  What do you want the proc to return?

Comment: actually I want the proc to return the data I just enter. Did I miss something here friend? I'm kinda in learning process for proc.

Comment: i already get the data i want,check it already. But does this store proc this will make my query to execute in never ending execution?

Answer (score 0):

If the product already exist, the update will process and then, your last SELECT. If the data doesn't exist, it will try inserting it and, if an error occurs, will set the values to the variables you declared, before returning it.

What are you expecting from your stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks,kind of understand it.